# Multiple Level Element Selection using Core JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How it could be possible in JavaScript. Select any X element on the base of some other selector

Like. I can do it using jQuery Some thing like that

```
x = $('#key').children('.left').children('input');
// In this example I am using id Selection, Class Selector and Element Selector
```

I tried to do this using JavaScript in this way

```
x = document.getElementById('key')
            .getElementByClassName('left')
            .getElementByName('input');
```

But i was unsuccessfully. I also search in on over the internet but there is no usefully solution for this. But How jQuery works in this Scenario for All Browser

Comment: post ur HTML code !!!

Comment: My Basic problem is selection of multiple element using CORE javaScript

Answer (score 1):

Using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#key > .left > input')
```

This is equivalent to jQuery version `$('#key').children('.left').children('input');`.

Support: IE8+.

Also note that you can also make use of `getElementsByClassName` (IE9+) and `getElementsByName` but it would be not so convenient if you really want to select direct children elements `>` and not all children. In this case I would go with `for` loops and `children` properties checking classes and tag names.

If you are okay with any depth elements and not only direct children I would recommend to go with [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName).